# Kotlin Multiplatform "actual" declaration in "commonTest" module not working: "no corresponding expected declaration"

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, unit-testing, kotlin-multiplatform

In my Kotlin Multiplatform project I have an expect class declared in "commonMain" module, with specific actual implementations in the "androidMain" and "iosMain". Problem is I am writing unit tests in for some shared code that should be in "commonTest" module. My expect class is a dependency of the class being tested, therefore I need to mock it since I don't really have an implementation defined yet (since the test shouldn't depend on the platform).

So what I want to do is define a third "actual" implementation of the class in the "commonTest" module, this implementation will be used only for testing. But I can't get it to work. I get a warning from Android Studio saying that the no corresponding expected declaration was found, even though it exists. "commonTest" should be able to see classes from the "commonMain" module, since those are the classes being tested, so why can't it find the expected declaration?

[image: Image showing the error]

Comment: `commonTest` is not one of platforms, so you can't use actual there. if your expect class has constructor to be used from common code, you can create it from test - it's gonna use platform implementation in each case. otherwise you can create `expect fun buildMockObject` and define it in `androidTest`/`iosTest` - there you can use your platform implementation. It's not an interface - on each platform you can only have one actual, and commonTest is "child" of commonMain, not a separate platform - when you run test there, it's gonna run same test on each platform(or you can manually select one)

Comment: @PhilDukhov I see... It seems actual and expect are quite limited and introduce a lot of problems like this, what advantages do they offer? I mean, from what I see I could achieve exact same thing defining interfaces and having different implementations in each platform, no? And that would also be more flexible when testing

Comment: you can have constructors and so create objects directly from common code. also when you access common from platform, you can interact with platform implementation  directly, without needing to check class type. expect class can subclass from an other class. I'm sure there're more use cases=) but in some cases interface is also cool